# Angular Js form validation error

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have written simple code for angular validation.
The create button should remain disabled util the user enters all the details.
But now the button does not get disabled.The code for form is,

```
<form name="networkIDForm" novalidate>
  <div class="ActsummaryHdrs pb10">Create Network ID</div>

  <div class="form-group clearfix " ng-class="{ 'has-error': networkIDForm.networkID.$touched && networkIDForm.networkID.$invalid }">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Network ID" name="networkID" class="form-control column48 pull-left " required/>


  </div>

  <div class="clearfix clearfix mt20">

    <div class="column48 pull-left form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': networkIDForm.firstname.$touched && networkIDForm.firstname.$invalid}">
      <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="column48 pull-left form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':  networkIDForm.lastname.$touched && networkIDForm.lastname.$invalid  }">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="clearfix mt20 mb10 form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': networkIDForm.email.$touched && networkIDForm.email.$invalid }">

    <input type="text" id="to" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control " required/>
  </div>



  <div class="clearfix mt20">

    <div class="column48 pull-left form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': networkIDForm.password.$touched && networkIDForm.password.$invalid }">
      <input class="form-control" type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="column48 pull-right form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':networkIDForm.cpassword.$touched && networkIDForm.cpassword.$invalid  }">
      <input type="Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="cpassword" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="clearfix mt20 mb10">

    <a id="CreateUserCreateBtn" class="btn general_btns_green pull-right ml5" ng-disabled="networkIDForm.$invalid">Create</a>
    <a id="CreateUserBackBtn" onclick="showCreateNetworkID()" class="btn general_btns_grey pull-right mr5" href="">Back</a>

  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Please format the code properly.

Comment: Have a look here : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-disabled-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `disable` anchor tag using `ng-disabled`.

Try to use `button` tag instead

```
<button  id="CreateUserCreateBtn" type="button"  class="btn general_btns_green pull-right ml5"  ng-disabled="networkIDForm.$invalid">Create</button>
```

or you can do it using **[ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)**

Like this

```
.not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}

<a id="CreateUserCreateBtn" class="btn general_btns_green pull-right ml5" ng-class="{'not-active' : networkIDForm.$invalid }">Create</a>
```

You are also missing `ng-model` in your form.

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/pqL8f3gf/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hi , 
I changed the anchor tag to button , but still the button is not getting disabled. Also if i hardcode ng-disabled to true in the anchor tag , the the button gets disabled.

Comment: @user3177493 can you provide jsfiddle ?

Comment: Thank you Anik. Hope fully  your code should help me :)

Comment: Hey thank you very much. The problem was with ng-model. Earlier i haven't include that. you saved my day buddy @Anik Islam Abhi